# Can a Mac OSX Plugin have its own Entitlements? Or extend the Main App's Entitlements?

Tags: macos, cocoa, plugins, sandbox, entitlements

I need to be able to define new entitlements (e.g. network access, file read) for my Print Dialog Extension (PDE) Plugin in Mac OSX 10.7 and above, where apps are now mostly sandboxed.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Edit: Looked at XPC services. XPC seems to not work, maybe because the PDE plugin runs on top of an app, e.g. Preview, and my XPC service is not within the Main App's bundle.

Comment: I am guessing it turned out that plugins/dynamic libraries don't have their own entitlements?